# jQuery plugin listnav not working with function properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am using [listNav](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-An-Alphabetical-Navigation-Filter-listnav.html) to alphabetize data from my database. If I hard code my list into the HTML page the plugin works like a charm. The problem is that the database has 2500+ entries and they will keep growing so it is time consuming to hard code the input every time there is an update.

I am using Javascript to read a json file and create the output that will be printed into the page. The output works fine, the issue is not there. The problem is that when I get the output from the `.js` file into my html page, the plugin does not recognize the `filterSelector` and it does not show an alphabetical navigation. I am not sure why, since it is the same output as if I was hard coding the output into the page.

Here is my `layout.js` file

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var collection = "";
    var obj = [];
    var html = '';
    var html2 = '';
    var html3 = '';
    $.getJSON( "getDBData.php", function(data) {
        var num = 1;
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        /* Here I get the information from the DB. No issues here*/
        }
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Beverly Crusher</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Crusher</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong>Rank:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Commander</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Oct. 13, 2324</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Wesley Crusher</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Crusher</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Ensign</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>July 29, 2349</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Data</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Data</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Lieutenant Commander</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Feb. 2, 2338</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Geordi La Forge</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">La Forge</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Commander</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Feb. 16, 2335</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Jean Luc Picard</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Picard</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Captain</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>July 13, 2305</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">William Riker</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Riker</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Captain</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>August 19, 2335</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Deanna Troi</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Troi</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Commander</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>March 29, 2336 (Terran equivalent)</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
        html2 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
        html2 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Worf</a></h2></span>';
        html2 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Worf</p>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Lieutenant Commander</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>December 9, 2340 (Terran equivalent)</span>        <br />';
        html2 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
        html2 += '            </span>';
    }
//        console.log(typeof(html2));
//        console.log(html2);
//        $('.dbOutput').html(html2);
});
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Beverly Crusher</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Crusher</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong>Rank:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Commander</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Oct. 13, 2324</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Wesley Crusher</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Crusher</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Ensign</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>July 29, 2349</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Data</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Data</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Lieutenant Commander</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Feb. 2, 2338</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Geordi La Forge</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">La Forge</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Commander</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Feb. 16, 2335</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Jean Luc Picard</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Picard</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Captain</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>July 13, 2305</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">William Riker</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Riker</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Captain</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>August 19, 2335</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="db_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Deanna Troi</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Troi</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Commander</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>March 29, 2336 (Terran equivalent)</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';
html3 += '            <span id ="type_span" class="bronze">';
html3 += '                <span class="company_name"><h2><a href="#">Worf</a></h2></span>';
html3 += '                <p hidden class="last-name">Worf</p>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span ><strong></strong>&nbsp;</span><span>Lieutenant Commander</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <span class="exhibitor_text"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong>&nbsp;</span><span>December 9, 2340 (Terran equivalent)</span>        <br />';
html3 += '                <a class ="exhibitor_text" href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Place of Birth:</a>        <br />';
html3 += '            </span>';

console.log(typeof(html3));
console.log(html3);
$('.dbOutput').html(html3);
});
```

Here is my `index.php` page

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/layout.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <style>
        /* Container for the alphabetical sirt */
        .tabContainer {
            -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;
            border-bottom: 10em;
            /*color:#333;*/
        }

        /* Navigation Bar for Alphabetical Sort */
        .listNav,
        .ln-letters { overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; }
        .listNavHide { display: none }
        .listNavShow { display: list-item }
        .letterCountShow { display: block }
        .ln-letters a {
            font-size: 0.9em;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 4%;
            border: 0px;
            border-right: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            color: 534C3E;
            /*background: white;*/
        }
        /*.ln-letters .ln-last { border-right: 1px solid silver }*/
        .ln-letters a:hover,.ln-letters .ln-selected { background-color: #eaeaea }
        .ln-letters .ln-disabled { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
        .ln-letter-count {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            line-height: 1.35;
            color: #534C3E
        }
        /*# sourceMappingURL=listnav.css.map */ 
    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <section class="contenido">
        <div class="envuelto">
            <div class="cuadrados">
                <div class="unidad completo">
                    <h2>Custumers DB</h2>
                    <div class="tabContainer"><div id="demoSix" class="dbOutput" ></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-listnav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#demoSix').listnav({
                includeAll: true,
                filterSelector: '.company_name',
                includeNums: false,
                showCounts: false,
                noMatchText: '',
                removeDisabled: true,
                allText: '&infin;'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I do the following in my layout.js page, it works like a charm, see image below

```
console.log(typeof(html3));
console.log(html3);
$('.dbOutput').html(html3);
```

[image: This is correct]

But if I comment the previous output and un-comment the following output the sorting option stops working, see the image below

```
console.log(typeof(html2));
console.log(html2);
$('.dbOutput').html(html2);
```

[image]

Why does it not work the same if is the same output? I tried different approaches and I am at a lost. It maybe something simple but why does the sorting opting works for the `html3` output but not the `html2` output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the scope for the function. I am not sure why this is the case since I am passing the right output. I have to add `function` call for the plugin to the `html` code in the js file and that fixed it, which meant adding this to the `layout.js file

```
html += '    <script>' + '\n';
html += '        $(function(){' + '\n';
html += '            $("#demoSix").listnav({' + '\n';
html += '                includeAll: true,' + '\n';
html += '                filterSelector: ".company_name",' + '\n';
html += '                includeNums: false,' + '\n';
html += '                showCounts: false,' + '\n';
html += '                noMatchText: "",' + '\n';
html += '                removeDisabled: true,' + '\n';
html += '                allText: "&infin;"' + '\n';
html += '            });' + '\n';
html += '        });' + '\n'; 
html += '    </script>';
```

So this is the new `layout.js` file

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var collection = "";
    var obj = [];
    var html = '';
    var html2 = '';
    var html3 = '';
    $.getJSON( "getDBData.php", function(data) {
        var num = 1;
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        html += '<div class="tabContainer">' + '\n';
        html += '<div id="demoSix">' + '\n';
        /* Here I get the information from the DB. No issues here*/
        }
    }
    html += '                </div>' + '\n';
    html += '            </div>' + '\n';
    html += '    <script>' + '\n';
    html += '        $(function(){' + '\n';
    html += '            $("#demoSix").listnav({' + '\n';
    html += '                includeAll: true,' + '\n';
    html += '                filterSelector: ".company_name",' + '\n';
    html += '                includeNums: false,' + '\n';
    html += '                showCounts: false,' + '\n';
    html += '                noMatchText: "",' + '\n';
    html += '                removeDisabled: true,' + '\n';
    html += '                allText: "&infin;"' + '\n';
    html += '            });' + '\n';
    html += '        });' + '\n'; 
    html += '    </script>';
    $('.dbOutput').html(html);
    });
});
```

And here is the `index.php` file

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/layout.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <style>
        /* Container for the alphabetical sirt */
        .tabContainer {
            -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px;
            border-bottom: 10em;
            /*color:#333;*/
        }

        /* Navigation Bar for Alphabetical Sort */
        .listNav,
        .ln-letters { overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; }
        .listNavHide { display: none }
        .listNavShow { display: list-item }
        .letterCountShow { display: block }
        .ln-letters a {
            font-size: 0.9em;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 4%;
            border: 0px;
            border-right: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            color: 534C3E;
            /*background: white;*/
        }
        /*.ln-letters .ln-last { border-right: 1px solid silver }*/
        .ln-letters a:hover,.ln-letters .ln-selected { background-color: #eaeaea }
        .ln-letters .ln-disabled { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
        .ln-letter-count {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            line-height: 1.35;
            color: #534C3E
        }
        /*# sourceMappingURL=listnav.css.map */ 
    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <section class="contenido">
        <div class="envuelto">
            <div class="cuadrados">
                <div class="unidad completo">
                    <h2>Customer's DB</h2>
                    <span class="dbOutput" ></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-listnav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I still not sure why the scope for the `listNav` function needs to be like this, but it works.